# Use Annotation for Java model class using Google GSON library

Tags: java, android, json, annotations, gson

I have a Java model class in an android app. I need to send an object of this class in Json format to a Web Service in C# (WCF).

```
public class Version {

    private String Core;
    private String FastInspektion;

    public String getCore() {
        return Core;
    }

    public void setCore(String core) {
        this.Core = core;
    }

    public String getFastInspektion() {
        return FastInspektion;
    }

    public void setFastInspektion(String fastInspektion) {
        this.FastInspektion = fastInspektion;
    }
```

They are using uppercase for first letters in C#, but in java we use lowercase. How can I use `Annotation` in java in order to change my fields to lowercase such as core instead of Core and etc?

Json creator:

```
this.gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
obj = new Version();
obj.setCore("lab lab...");
obj.setFastInspektion("lab lab...");
gson.toJson(newobj);
```

Comment: What JSON generator are you using? The class you are showing is from C# or Java?

Comment: I am using Google Gson library. I have added an example at the end of the question. The class is in Java. And the Gson lib convert the model object to a jso format.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Gson, you can annotate your field with `@SerializedName` to give it a different JSON name. (You say the class is in Java, but your field names are capitalized.)

Typically

```
private String core;
```

would produce

```
{"core":"some value"}
```

Instead, use

```
@SerializedName("Core")
private String core;
```

which produces

```
{"Core":"some value"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@SerializedName("Core") private String Core;
@SerializedName("FastInspektion") private String FastInspektion;
```

As described [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html), the annotation goes with the class member. Note also that in Java, typically field members (and other variables) begin with a lower-case letter.